# Code redundancy making it faster?

Tags: javascript, performance

EDIT: Seems to have disappeared.

I've benchmarked some parts of my code and found out that
if its like this:

```
if(oneCondition)  
{
   performOne();
   performOne_two();

   abc();
   def();
   gh();
} else
{
   performTwo();
   performTwo_two();

   abc();
   def();
   gh();
}
```

it runs significantly faster than if its like this:

```
if(oneCondition)  
{
   performOne();
   performOne_two();
} else
{
   performTwo();
   performTwo_two();
}

abc();
def();
gh();
```

(In relation: the first version takes around 585ms while the second version takes around 610-630ms).

Can someone explain me why?

This is the code part: (Its part of a backpropagation algorithm for a neural network)

https://pastebin.com/9WfEJdPt // I have moved on

Comment: Does this code run many times? Is there any logic behind oneCondition?

Comment: It runs around 800.000 times not just that block, but in total (its like 100.000 * block1, block1 runs block2 4 times, and block3 runs this block 2 times). And the condition is just "if(numberX == numberY - 1) "

Comment: And how did you perform those tests? I don't want to call bs on them but the only difference is that they are exiting the logical operator and that does not take ~30ms so surely it's something inside those functions that causes a disruption. Is the same data fed each time?

Comment: It both runs 800.000 times so the difference in the run times should be actually existing (i also ran the test multiple times), and i just compared the two version with console.time. "abc();
def();
gh();" always do the same, and "performOne();
   performOne_two();", "performTwo();
   performTwo_two();" aswell

Comment: Please post your actual code so that we can reproduce your results. Otherwise we will neither be able to confirm your measurements nor be able to explain why.

Comment: Maybe the engine sees three small functions that are repeated and caches them? In the second case they're called only once and they're not cached. Just an idea. To check on that you could create functions with the same body but different names and call them, and see if you still get the performance gain.

Comment: JIT can potentially optimize your branches based on ``oneCondition``being true or false.

Comment: Added a link that shows the code part.

Comment: If your 3 redundant methods depend on variables that are changed in the `if` or `else` blocks, you cannot compare the execution time, as the data are not the same. I was not able to reproduce your behavior (with simple time-consuming functions) using benchmark.js.

Comment: Have you tested with multiple browsers?

Comment: Both ways result in the same thing. So not really different data

Comment: I run it in Nodejs

Comment: @FabianSchneider Can you make that a [mcve], please? Where are all the variables coming from and what values do they contain?

Comment: Thanks for your will to help, but look at "Adriani6" ' s test, (http://jsfiddle.net/S72Fa/81/) he replicated it, and gets the same result. His way is minimal and i cant change my code to be minimal, also because the rest around it currently doesnt work.

Comment: @FabianSchneider If you take the jsfiddle, and invert the order of the functions (invert `func1` and `func2`), you will see that whichever one is the first is gonna perform better. So I think this is not related to wether or not a function call is redundant, but more which function is called first. Maybe related to the JIT compiler as stated in another comment.

Comment: @Seblor Well, that was a poor framework...  lol

Comment: Further to @Seblor comment.  exchanging the names (rename them) of the functions makes the original func2 the faster one, changing the order of them as parameters to `measure([func1,func2]);` to `measure([func2,func1]);` makes func2 the faster and measure([func1,func2,func1,func2,func1,func2]); will have them settle down to equal timings.  My best guess is that the JIT figures out some sort of an inlining of the first one called but as things get more complicated it falls back.

Comment: Well ok, thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @Adriani6 My guess is that `measureOne` suffers from becoming [polymorphic](https://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html) when being called with the second function. That's why warmup is important!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for that! I've skimmed through it and it looks like a good read, will read it later on for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

The linked code uses the same functions with a different data feed/argument. Your JIT apparently found a way to optimise at least one of the common functions for at least one of those matrix types. Most likely you have either `pExpectedOutput` or `this.weightMatrixes[layerNr + 1]` hardcoded. Ideally the JIT should be able to make this distinction by itself, eliminating the need for redundant code.

Comment: No, same data. pExpectedOutput is hardcoded. The huge difference has vanished now though, there was a bug with the data somewhere and after fixing it the performance difference between the two became 0, or atleast very small. Thanks for your time btw.!